# SQLite.Interop.dll. Не удается загрузить

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Доброе утро. У меня вопрос. Я создал UserControl и добавил в tabPage. Из базы данных беру данные в UserControl. Вопрос первый. "SQLite.Interop.dll. Не удается загрузить" Это серьезная проблема или нет? Как можно решить? Сам SQLite.Interop.dll в References нету, а в проекте в папке существует. Заранее спасибо. Теперь у меня вообще не работает все. Когда добавляю UserCOntrol в Winforms.

Comment: не серьёзная :) указать в ссылку на *.DLL в Referenses

Comment: @Alias, SQLite.Interop.dll нативная библиотека, не управляемая же

Comment: @Сергей не понял, как бы это могло помешать найти её обзором, вот только что скачал на пробу Нугет-пакет и натравил на SQLite.Interop.dll студию; ну и ниже вы пишете ответ про выставление свойства `CopyToOutputDirectory=true` подразумевая её нахождение в References ?

Comment: line 21: SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString);

Answer (score 3):

Для работы с SQLite вам нужно подключить `System.Data.SQLite`, а библиотеку `SQLite.Interop` положить рядом с exe-файлом тогда `System.Data.SQLite` сама найдет её.

Comment: Сделал как вы написали, ничего не поменялось.

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял из такой скудной вводной - вам в проекте надо выставить у DLL свойство `CopyToOutputDirectory` в `true`.

Comment: @Alias Вы имеете ввиду добавить в References *.dll файл?

Comment: В Copy to Output Directory есть только: 1. Do Not copy 2. Copy always 3.Copy if never

Comment: Я решил проблему. Вот ссылка http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/29888-NET-Error-specified-module-could-not-be.aspx

Comment: Нужно было копировать SQLite.Interop.dll и вставить C:\Windows\System32

Comment: Или в одну папку с выходным exe

Comment: так пробовал, чета не получилось